# How can I test method calling QMetaObject::invokeMethod with Qt::QueuedConnection -- using gtest gmock framework

Tags: c++, qt, googletest, signals-slots, qmetaobject

Suppose I have a method and I want to test it using gtest/gmock framework. This method calls another method inside itself using a Qt queued invoke:

```cpp
void MyClass::handleFoo()
{
    // ...
    Q_ASSERT(QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "handleBar", Qt::QueuedConnection));
}

void MyClass::handleBar()
{
    _view.show();
}
```

```cpp
TEST_F(MyTestSuite, MyTest)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(_viewMock, show()); // Fails with never called

    emit _myClassObj->foo();

    // Tried QCoreApplication::processEvents() -- does not help
}
```

Is there any way to do it? I think maybe I should just test these two handlers separately. But how can I test that the method `handleFoo()` will indeed call `handleBar()`?

Comment: And that `_view` of yours is a mocked object when called inside the `handleBar()` invocation?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually it worked all quite great before I realized that I should "move out" some execution from handleFoo() to be called after returning to the event loop,

Comment: And if you use the direct connection in `invokeMethod` then it gets called?

Comment: Yes, I have just double checked that when I use Qt::DirectConnection, the test succeeds, i.e. the mock is called.

Comment: Then you need to find out why `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` didn't help you. If you aren't using threads then it should have helped, if you are using threads then you should call it on the corresponding thread.

Comment: I don't use threads.

Comment: I honestly don't know why processEvents() does not help. If I understand right it should synchronously call my handleBar() but it does not.

Comment: Oh, I think I have guessed what the problem is! I do not have a QCoreApplication in my gtest main.cpp. Lol. I am not sure -- can I call the event loop without it?

Comment: You need an event loop to work with the Qt plumbing properly. Either use `QEventLoop` or create a `QCoreApplication` application which will do it for you.

Comment: I see. I will try and update on the result. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I have created a QCoreApplication right in the beginning of my unit test, and then I called QCoreApplication::processEvents() at the end of  the test and everything worked out.

Comment: I discovered that sometimes QCoreApplication::processEvents()  has to be called twice to  fire the needed event. To cure this, I now use QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(&*_myClassObj);